SFML sound not playing (no errors)(volume=100)(looping=false)
I have a problem: I have the following in the code, and the game logic is in another file. When I call play, it works, but the sound plays too frequently. I created play_delay, "playing" is printed, but the sound itself does not play, even though it works after this if statement.
The "playing" is printed repeatedly, but the sound doesn’t play. What is the problem?
#include "include/sound.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Sound::Sound(const char* sound_file_path) :
    _last_play_time(.0f) {
    if (!_sound_buffer.loadFromFile(sound_file_path))
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load sound file");
    _sound_sound.setBuffer(_sound_buffer);

    _sound_sound.setVolume(100);
}

void Sound::play(void) {
    _sound_sound.play();
}

void Sound::play_delay(const sf::Time& delta_time, float sound_play_delay) {
    _last_play_time += delta_time.asSeconds();
    if (_last_play_time >= sound_play_delay) {
        std::cout << "playing" << std::endl;
        _sound_sound.play();
        _last_play_time = 0.0f;
    }
}


Can you post a minimal main function that calls these functions and reproduces the problem? It seems odd that "playing" prints but the sound won't play, so there might be something going on in your game logic contributing to the problem
